# Android: Set windowIsTranslucent from Activity

Tags: android, window, transparent

I'm developing a library where I have to set the window background programmatically and I can't use custom style XMLs. The idea is that the user who implements the library can set any theme he want - I just need to make the background transparent. So all the styles for the widgets will stay the same.

I tried some window flags like `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`, but none of them was working.

Every solution that I've found is based on the style xml file.

Is there a way to set windowIsTranslucent directly from the code?

Thanks in advance, Roman

Comment: FYI, FLAG_DIM_BEHIND is used for dialogs, while FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is no longer supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

It is only possible to set `windowIsTranslucent` in your theme.

Suggestion; Create your own theme that others can override.

Comment: But there is an attribute available: android.R.attr.windowIsTranslucent - Is there no way to set this?

Comment: No, this has to be done in the theme. It adjusts the Window which can not be changed on runtime. So you need to restart the activity/window before changing the windowIsTranslucent attribute.

Comment: This is no longer true, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77334990/7362988)

Answer (score 0):

`android:windowIsTranslucent`, `android:windowIsFloating`, and `android:windowNoDisplay` are all read exactly once, before your activity has even started. So by the time you're running your own code, it's too late.

http://osxr.org:8080/android/source/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java#0399

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    processSetTheme(this);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.realTranslucent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19){
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

<color name="realTranslucent">#00000000</color>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is trick:
First you use Translucent activity.
then you can set background of activity's layout file top layout.